# Error in passing Query string parameter in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

I am working in classic asp and not much familiar with syntax
I have this JavaScript on my parent page

```
function redirect(ID)
{
 document.frmMain.action = "manual.asp?ID=" + ID;
 alert('manual.asp?ID='+ID)
 document.frmMain.submit();
}
```

But the same ID when I am capturing on new asp page its coming empty.

```
<%   
SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE ID='" & Request.QueryString("ID") & "'"
set rst = DataConn.Execute(SQLStr)
Denied = 1
while not rst.eof
    Denied = 0
    rst.movenext
wend
rst.close
if Denied = 1 then  
%>
```

Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom (xkcd)](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form you're using for the redirect is empty you should better use `window.location` for this task

```
function redirect(id) {
    window.location.href = "manual.asp?id=" + id;
}
```

If the form isn't empty, you will have to add a field for the id and fill this with the parameter.

```
<form name="frmMain" action="manual.asp" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="paramter1" value="1" />
    <!-- hidden value for the id -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
</form>


function redirect(id) {
    var form = document.frmMain;
    form.id.value = id;
    form.submit();
}
```

But you will still have to check the id parameter for any illegal chars which may break your database [read me](http://diovo.com/2008/09/sanitizing-user-data-how-and-where-to-do-it/)

Comment: Thanks Andreas: Will check the solution u provided